# CSS how can i turn the scrolling off during the animation?

Tags: html, css

How can I turn the scrolling off during the animation in CSS?
But I don't want to give `overflow:hidden` to the body.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help you with your CSS we first need to see your ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) HTML and attempted CSS, so we can try and solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this one problem.

Comment: Dear Andreas here is my code.  http://codepen.io/vahik95/pen/zBJVAP

Comment: Ok, so why not set overflow:hidden; to the body? Works perfectly fine for me...

Comment: When I set overflow:hidden; and zoom the page I need a scroll,but at th time of overflow:hidden; i don't have a scroll for zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to set a specific CSS rule after an animation is completed with pure CSS.

If possible for you, you can use JavaScript to delay the turning back to the normal scrolling behaviour after e.g. 5 seconds. Below's an example with jQuery.

CSS (add overflow rule to body):

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setTimeout(changeOverflow, 5000); // set overflow back to auto after 5s
});

function changeOverflow() {
  $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
}
```

See the [forked CodePen](http://codepen.io/devmount/pen/BzOgZQ).